# Icecast : send output parameters in a mountpoint

Tags: icecast, internet-radio

I have defined a mount point in my Icecast server, for example data.ogg. I would like to send some parameters to the mount point I have defined, for example /data.ogg?param1=x1&param2=x2&param3=x3. I have tried to parse these parameters in a new script and I could only parse the mount point /data.ogg. I have the following question:
How to parse the other parameters (param1,param2 and param3) in a new script? I have written a script and tried to parse all the parameters sent as $1,$2,$3 
but din't find any result.
An example of the script would be :

```
echo $1 >/tmp/viewls.txt
echo $! >/tmp/viewls2.txt
echo $3 >/tmp/viewls3.txt
```

Any idea on how to do it ?
Thanks
GOrka

Comment: What do you mean, "send some parameters to the mount point"?  When GET requests come in?  When a source connects?  What's your config look like right now?

Comment: I mean when you config the mount point in the icecast.xml file how to send some fet parameters to that mounpoint. For example http://localhost/data.ogg?data1=param1&data2=param2. How to parse those parameters param1 and param2

Comment: Parse them with what?  Show us your config.

Comment: Hello Brad. This is the icecast.xml file I use :\n

Comment: Hello Brad.  I try to reproduce an rstp streaming in icecast using the following url:localhost/data.ogg?data1=param1&data2=param2. Previously in the ubuntu machine I am sending a rstp video streaming to the icecast server using vlc. The icecast server used is the following : rstp://**************       This is the icecast.xml file I use <mount type="normal"><mount-name>/data.ogg</mount-name><fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full<charset>UTF-8</charset><bitrate>128</bitrate><on-connect>/bin/testIcecast.sh</on-connect></mount><paths> Any idea ?